# cancellation_token is set to canceled state immediately after its creation

Tags: c++, winapi, cancellation-token

I am having problems creating a cancellation token in a Win32 application. I create it in the following way. In the main application file, where the `int APIENTRY wWinMain()` and `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc` are defined, I define:

```
static cancellation_token_source cts;
```

Then, in the `WndProc()` window procedure, I write the following:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    . . . . . .
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
             . . . . . .
             case IDM_TRIANGULATE: // Click on the triangulation start button
             {
                 // Get a cancellation token to cancel "triangulationTask" task.
                 cancellation_token token = cts.get_token();
                 // Triangulation mesh
                 Mesh m;
                 // Application configuration parameters
                 Configuration b;
                 // Define a task to perform triangulation.
                 auto triangulationTask = create_task([&m, &b, &token]()
                 {
                      // Check if the task was canceled.
                      if (token.is_canceled())
                      {
                          // Cancel triangulation.
                          Concurrency::cancel_current_task();
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          // Run triangulation.
                          DelaunayTriangulation delaunayTri;
                          m.HullSize = delaunayTri.StartTriangulation(&m, &b, token);
                      }
                 });
             }
             . . . . . .
        }
   }
    . . . . . .
}
```

When I run the application in debug mode, I constantly get to the branch

```
if (token.is_canceled()) {}
```

i.e., it turns out that the token is created already canceled (set to the *is_canceled* state when it is created). Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `token` variable is local to the `IDM_TRIANGULATE` handler and goes out of scope once `create_task()` exits, but the task lambda is capturing a reference to that variable. The reference is invalid once the variable goes out of scope. As such, your code has **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, if I  declare the token in a global scope, then (when it is initialized in WndProc) the next error occures: 'Concurrency::cancellation_token::cancellation_token': cannot access private member declared in class 'Concurrency::cancellation_token'. But I need initialize token each time the button pressed.

Comment: the `token` variable has to remain in scope for the lifetime of the task that users it. Just as for any other variable. Since you have only 1 `cancellation_token_source`, you can grab its `token` at the same time you create `cts`: `static cancellation_token_source cts; static cancellation_token token = cts.get_token();`

Comment: @Remy Lebeay, During the session with the program, the user can start and cancel triangulation several times. Accordingly, WndProc will execute several times: IDM_TRIANGULATE / IDM_STOP. IDM_STOP has a call to cts.cancel () to cancel the task. How do I determine the cancellation token in my code in this case?

Comment: a cancelation token can't be reset once it is cancelled, so you would need to create a new cancelation source per IDM_TRIANGULATE request and have IDM_STOP cancel the latest token. And you still need to keep each source+token in scope for the lifetime of each task. So a single global/static cancelation source won't work in your situation.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, please give the example of code. Because I spent three hours and could not do it right. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: I've done: static  cancellation_token_source cancelTriSource;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){switch (message){case WM_COMMAND:{case IDM_TRIANGULATE:{auto asyncTask = create_task([](){       cancelTriSource = cancellation_token_source();    cancellation_token token = cancelTriSource.get_token();auto triangulationTask = create_task([&token](){/*triangulation is done here*/}, token);});break;}break;}}} And now my application works.

Comment: you don't need to create 2 tasks, 1 will suffice. And you don't need to capture the `token` in the lambda by reference, if at all, capture by value will suffice. `static  cancellation_token_source cancelTriSource;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){ switch (message){ case WM_COMMAND:{ case IDM_TRIANGULATE:{ cancelTriSource = cancellation_token_source();    cancellation_token token = cancelTriSource.get_token(); auto triangulationTask = create_task([token](){/*triangulation is done here*/}, token); break;}}}}`

Comment: ayncTask waits of completion of triangulationTask using the call of triangulationTask.get();. So that source and token are kept in scope for the lifetime of triangulationTask.

Comment: there is no good reason to  create 2 tasks just to have 1 wait on the other. That is a waste of a thread and effectively the same as using 1 task, so just use 1 task. Did you even try the code I gave you?

Comment: Yes, I had tryed and had the following problems: 1) If triangulationTask is not waited then token is is_cancelled. 2) If triangulationTask is waited then the application hangs. Because of this, I did two tasks for asynchronouse working.

Comment: Oh, I bag your pardon. I've passed token by reference to lambda not by value. I'll try again with passing of token by value.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, unfortunately, errors appear and, therefore, I decided to take the version with two tasks. After all, I have two more parameters (Mesh m, Configuration b) that I need to pass by reference. Thank you very much for your support and help.